# Systems of ODE (Eigenvalue method[CLARIFICATION])

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-decomposition

I'm doing differential equations (systems of ODE)

The equation:
$$\begin{bmatrix}2 & 7 \\-5 & -10\end{bmatrix}$$

I have found $\lambda$ to be -3 and -5

For $\lambda$ = -5 substituted into the 2x2 determinant matrix, we get

$$\begin{bmatrix}7 & 7 \\-5 & -5\end{bmatrix}$$

Now, I said $7x_1 = -7x_2 \implies x_1 = -x_2$ then I have the corresponding eigenvector of $$\begin{bmatrix}-1 \\1\end{bmatrix}$$
but the given solution has $$\begin{bmatrix}1 \\-1\end{bmatrix}$$

Therefore, part of my general solution for the equation is .... + $C_2e^{-5t}\begin{bmatrix}-1 \\1\end{bmatrix}$. Is that acceptable? Or is this wrong and the solution is right?

Thanks! TGIF

Comment: Any multiple of an eigenvector is also an eigenvector.  In particular [1, -1] is -1 times [-1, 1].

Comment: user247327 is correct about your problem. Note that $C_2$ is an arbitrary constant, so your eigenvector will just have the opposite value for $C_2$ than the book eigenvector to produce the same function.